# iOS silent notification cases

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, silentpush

For silent push notification I have implemented this method :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
        {
            if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue]== 1) //it's the silent notification
            {

                UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    // CASE - 1  
 if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground ) 
                {

                    //Badge increment
                }
    // CASE -2 for foreground 
 else  {


                    //Badge increment
                }

                handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                return;
            }
```

**Two scenario**

1) I want to decrease the badge count when user clicks the notification .(app comes to foreground)

2)  and take no action in badge when notification arrives while (app is in foreground ).

But for both the scenarios , same code is executed . And badge decrement occurs . (Commented as CASE - 2).

How to act according to these scenarios  .